# Cannot use Data Binding in other package(library/sdk) except enabling dataBinding in main app gradle module

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

Well, I'm working on a library/SDK that has activities/fragments and I want to use data binding instead of the findViewById() method.

But i got this error message when I enabled **dataBinding-> enabled = true** in **library gradle module** but **not** enabled in the **app:gradle module**.

This is the error I got:

```
Failed resolution of: Landroidx/databinding/DataBinderMapperImpl;

Didn't find class "androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapperImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.raychat.raychat_sdk-eNdusNjUCa3sHWzKRK-iqw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.raychat.raychat_sdk-eNdusNjUCa3sHWzKRK-iqw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

The user of this library is different and I can't tell all of them to enable data binding in app:gradle module. what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [Data Binding Library - Get Started](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#build_environment)

> You must configure data binding for app modules that depend on libraries that use data binding, even if the app module doesn't directly use data binding.

So when you develop a library and you can not force your library clients to enable data binding, you simply should not use it.

Have you considered using [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) instead?

Comment: Yes this way the end user does not need to enable it in build:gradle and it's faster in compilation rather than data binding. Thanks.